# Error! { [CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value at path "_id"]

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, http-get

I was following http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html to learn how to populate an array of references I had. However, when I try to perform an HTTP Get request on the populated array, I get an error that says

```
Error! { [CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "blah" at path "_id"]
  message: 'Cast to ObjectId failed for value "blah" at path "_id"',
  name: 'CastError',
  type: 'ObjectId',
  value: 'blah',
  path: '_id' }
```

With `blah` being the value inside the array. Below is my attempt:

HTTP Get call:

```
$scope.user = Auth.getCurrentUser();

$http.get('/api/users/' + $scope.user._id)
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
        $scope.currentUser = data;
    });
```

User Schema:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  username: String,
  eventsAttending: [{ type: String, ref: 'Event'}],
});
```

and HTTP GET function:

```
router.get('/:id', controller.getEvents);
exports.getEvents = function(req, res) {
  User.findById(req.params.id).populate('eventsAttending').exec(function(err, events){
    if(err) {
      console.log("Error!", err);
      return res.send(500, err);
    }
    return res.json(200, events);
  });
};
```

I honestly am not too sure why the values inside my array are being casted into Object Ids. I clearly specified that the contents in the array are Strings, not Object Id's which will be references to the the Event Schema. I know that the contents inside my array are simple Strings. Any idea why this is happening?

Edit: I am posting a sample object. In here lies the eventsAttending array I want to populate:

```
{
  "name" : "Jane Doe",
  "username" : "jane93",
  "eventsAttending" : [
      "blah",
      "TestEvent",
      "Asdf",
      "TestEvent2"
  ]
}
```

Comment: You're using the `populate` function, which I believe casts `_id` references into `ObjectId` instances by default.

Comment: Are you requesting `/api/users/blah`? `blah` is not a correct ObjectId.

Comment: It looks like that the contains inside your array are not as the format of ObjectId. Check them. Also it is recommended to use `Schema.Types.ObjectId` instead of `String`. ObjectId uses smaller space, it don't need to convert from String to ObjectId so it is faster, and you can't put wrong type value in it.

Comment: @FoadNosratiHabibi
I am requesting /api/users/<objectId>. My array does contain Strings as you can see by my schema above. is it possible to use populate on Strings as opposed to Object Ids?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Can you put real sample of your array in here?

Comment: @FoadNosratiHabibi I just added in a sample of my Object stored inside my collection. The eventsAttending array is the array that contains the strings.

Comment: Ok! It looks like that `blah` is the value that you use! Yes as I said it can store as string or ObjectId, but it should be valid ObjectId and `blah` is not. You can simply check it in mongodb shell by `ObjectId("blah")` and see that it reports: `Unexpected token ILLEGAL`. Sample of valid one is: `53f38c41cac908f7810b3282`.

Comment: @FoadNosratiHabibi okay, that makes sense. I understand that I need to populate for ObjectId's as opposed to Strings. However, if possible, I still want to keep the contents as the strings shown above, and not ObjectIds. Is it possible to use populate in these strings as opposed to the ObjectIds you mention? Or is it possible to change my query in a way so that it looks for Strings as opposed to ObjectIds?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59599/discussion-between-foad-nosrati-habibi-and-user1567909).